# String operation in python: handling the queries of a simple search engine

Tags: python, search-engine, python-re, string-operations

I am implementing a simple search engine that searches in a source data which is the 12k pieces of written-news of different topics. We assume that the search engine just have the ability to respond to:

1. ***Phrase Queries*** that come with inside of the double-quotation marks
2. ***Not Queries*** that come after the exclamation mark
3. ***And Queries*** which come without any specific mark

For instance this query:

### *"global warming" worldwide !USA*

is a query that should contain:

1. the ***Phrase Query***: *"global warming"*
2. the ***And Query***: *worldwide*
3. not contain the ***Not Query***: *USA*

The point is that the ***Phrase Query*** should come continuously in a unique piece with no other words between the words!
My problem is with splitting these three types of queries using string operation of Python or re library.

I have write this piece of code for extracting ***Phrase Queries*** and ***Not Queries***. but I have not handled to extract the ***And queries*** yet!

```
query = input()
phrase_query = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', query)
not_query = re.findall(r'!(\w+)', query)
print(phrase_query)
print(not_query)
```

For the input of:

### *"global warming" worldwide !USA*

the above code returns:

```
['global warming']
['USA']
```

Which is great. However I can not extract the ***And Query***. How can I extract the ***And Query***: *worldwide* in a different list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correct, anything that is not a part of the *phase query* and the *not query*, is part of the *and query*. So, we can essentially just remove the terms that come in those queries from the string and then split it to get the individual terms.

```
import re

data = '"global warming" worldwide !USA'

query = data
phrase_query = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', query)
not_query = re.findall(r'!(\w+)', query)

and_query = data[:]

for q in phrase_query:
    complete_text = '"' + q + '"'
    and_query = and_query.replace(complete_text, "")
for q in not_query:
    complete_text = "!" + q
    and_query = and_query.replace(complete_text, "")

and_query = and_query.split()


print(and_query)
print(phrase_query)
print(not_query)
```

So, what I am doing here is, in the first for loop, I am looping over all the phrase queries and then completing them by adding the quotes before and after, just like they would be shown in the original query. Then I will replace them with a blank string. So it would basically just remove them. After that, I am doing a similar thing with all the not queries, but this time I am adding an exclamation in the front.

Then, the remaining terms in the search are all *and queries*, so we can split them to get those terms individually in a list.

---

**EDIT for a more robust solution(one that handles spaces effectively)**:

```
import re

data = '" global warming " worldwide ! USA'

query = data
phrase_query = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', query)
not_query = re.findall(r'!([^w+]*)', query)

and_query = data[:]

for q in phrase_query:
    complete_text = '"' + q + '"'
    and_query = and_query.replace(complete_text, "")
for q in not_query:
    complete_text = "!" + q
    and_query = and_query.replace(complete_text, "")

and_query = [answer.strip() for answer in and_query.split()]
phrase_query = [answer.strip() for answer in phrase_query]
not_query = [answer.strip() for answer in not_query]


print(and_query)
print(phrase_query)
print(not_query)
```

Comment: Thanks man. That is a good solution if there is no spaces inserted between double-quotation and exclamation marks. But what is the solution if there were some spaces in between?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you mean to say.

the solution works for this input ``data = '" global warming " worldwide !USA'
``.
Is this what you mean to say(spaces in between the double-quotation)?

Comment: For instance this solution does not work for this query:
" global warming " worldwide ! USA
I inserted a single space between "!" and USA
Also I need to extract Phrase Queries, Not Queries, and And Queries without the beginning and ending spaces.

Comment: I have edited the solution to meet your needs, please check if this works better

Comment: nope
It returns like this for Phrase Query, Not Query, and And Query respectively:

['global warming']
[]
['"', 'global', 'warming', '"', 'worldwide', '!', 'USA']

Comment: I guess its better to correct the re phrase which I defined for Phrase and Not Queries. Right?

Comment: No, When I run this query I get the result of - ['worldwide']
['global warming']
['USA']

Which is what we want

Comment: Here, try going on this link https://replit.com/@VedRathi/String-operation-in-python-handling-the-queries-of-a-simple#main.py and running the given repl. It matches the edited code exactly and gives the correct output